# Azure storage account - Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: azure, c#-4.0, azure-storage

I have logged onto to Azure Portal and created a storage account and the container to hold the images. (container has the access type set to container).
Now I'm trying to upload an image using the C# code.(Works fine on uploading an image via portal and able to access the image.)

```
//   actName contains the storage account name and actKey contains the Access Key for that storage account.

StorageCredentials creds = new StorageCredentials(actName, actKey);
CloudStorageAccount imageStorageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(creds, useHttps: true);

CloudBlobClient blobClient = imageStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();


CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("newimages");
container.CreateIfNotExists();
```

It is throwing an error:

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it 51.136.40.24:443

Any input on this will be helpful.

Update 19/12/2016
It required me to change the Identity from ApplicationPoolIdentity to Custom user name and account. Is there a way to work on it without changing the ApplicationPoolIdentity?

Comment: Looks like some connectivity issue from the machine where the code is run. If possible, please check if there's a proxy/firewall in picture which is blocking the connection.

Comment: Your code seems ok. Please try to use fiddler to capture and check the request of accessing Azure blob storage.